# Check if the following defines a (total) order ($x\leq_p y$ iff the largest prime factor of $x$ is $\leq$ the largest prime factor of $y$)

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, ordered-fields

Let $(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}, \leq_p)$ with $x\leq_p y$ iff the largest prime factor of $x$ is $\leq$ the largest prime factor of $y$. Check if this defines a (total) order by checking the four order axioms.

---

To verify that this is a valid order I must verify the four axioms of order relations:

O1. Reflexivity: $x \leq x$.

O2. Anti-symmetry: $x \leq y \land y \leq x \Rightarrow x=y$.

O3. Transivitity: $x \leq y \land y \leq z \Rightarrow x \leq z$.

O4. Total order: $\forall x,y\in X: x\leq y \lor y \leq x$.

---

I really have no idea how to show this. I assume this wouldn't be enough for the first three axioms, right?

Let the largest prime factor of $x := p(x)$.

O1. $p(x) = p(x)$ and as such the axiom is fulfilled.

O2. If $p(x) \leq p(y) \land p(y) \leq p(x) \Rightarrow p(x)=p(y)$.

O3. ?

With O4 being shown through induction.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not quite the right approach. Here is what you need just for O1 and O2:

O1. We need to show $x \le_p x$ for any $x$ in the domain. Well, since $p(x) \le p(x)$ we have that $x \le_p x$, and as such the axiom is fulfilled.

O2. We need to show that if $x \le_p y$ and $y \le_p x$, then $x=y$ for any $x$ and $y$ in the domain. Well, if $x \le_p y$ and $y \le_p x$, then  $p(x) \leq p(y)$ and $p(y) \leq p(x)$. This indeed means $p(x)=p(y)$ ... but does that mean $x=y$?

HINT

> Take $x=2$ and $y=4$. They both have $2$ as the greatest prime factor, and so we have $x \le_p y$ and $y \le_p x$, but we don't have $x=y$. So, it is not anti-symmetric

Comment: I see, thank you very much. So for O3 I would proceed similarly to O2, yes? Would proceeding by induction be the right approach for O4?

Comment: @math_mu If by 'similarly' you mean being very careful about exactly what you need to show, and to distinguish between a claim like $p(x) \le p(y)$  and $x \le _p y$, then yes.  For O4 you don't need induction (in fact, I have no idea how induction would help with that one at all...).  But in the end, since we found O2 doesn't hold, we already know this is not an order, so why bother with O3 and O4?

Comment: Oh, my exercise requires me to check all axioms. I should have been more clear about that. Thank you for your response.

I supposed induction would be the right approach for O4 since that is how I saw the general order on $\mathbb{N}$ being proven while searching online.

Comment: @math_mu OK, well, why don't you give O3 and O4 a new shot and update your post ...